# Swift with Vapor: optionally update model field based in request

Tags: swift, vapor

I am creating a basic CRUD using Swift and Vapor (server-side).

In my controller I created a new method: “edit”. In this method, it’s possible update user’s password and roles. **IF** the request has a password data, update the password. **IF** the request has a new array of roles, update the roles (sibling relationship which is not done yet).

This is the "edit" method in my Controller:

```
func edit(request:Request, id:String) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {
    // Check if the password came in POST request:
    let password = request.data["password"]?.string

    // Check if the request has a new set of roles
    let roles = request.data["roles"]?.array

    let user:ClinicUser = try ClinicUser.edit(id: id, password: password, roles: roles)
    return user
}
```

And in my model the edit method looks like this:

```
static func edit(id:String, password:String?, roles:Array<NodeRepresentable>?) throws -> ClinicUser {
    guard var user:ClinicUser = try ClinicUser.find(id) else {
        throw Abort.notFound
    }
    // Is it the best way of doing this? Because with "guard" I should "return" or "throw", right?
    if password != nil {
        user.password = try BCrypt.hash(password: password!)
    }
    
    // TODO: update user's roles relationships

    try user.save()
    
    return user
}
```

In my controller, there is an error pointed by XCode that says `Cannot convert value of type '[Polymorphic]?' to expected argument type 'Array<NodeRepresentable>'`. And, as fix, Xcode suggests write like this:

```
let user:ClinicUser = try ClinicUser.edit(id: id, password: password, roles: roles as! Array<NodeRepresentable>)
```

I am not sure if this is safe or if this it is a best practice (forcing the unwrap with **!**).

I do not know if in Swift I should "think" differently than other languages (like PHP, etc.). In the end, what I want is:

```
static func edit(id:String, fieldA:String?, fieldN:String, etc..) throws -> ClinicUser {
    // If fieldA is available, update fieldA:
    if fieldA != nil {
        model.fieldA = fieldA
    }

    // If fieldN is available, update fieldN:
    if fieldN != nil {
        model.fieldN = fieldN
    }
    
    // After update all fields, save:
    try model.save()
    
    // Return the updated model:
    return model
}
```

Comment: is xcode suggests working fine?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you could do the following:

```
// Check if the request has a new set of roles
let rolesArray = request.data["roles"]?.array
guard let roles = rolesArray as? Array<NodeRepresentable>
else {
    // throw "SomeError" or return "Some other response"
}
```

Xcode complains because it can't specify the type of the array you are getting out of your request data at compile time.

As a result you must downcast it to a more specific type.

You have two options to do so.

1. as! -> will trigger a runtime error if it fails
2. as? -> will return nil if it fails

So if you use as? and guard, in case of failure you can interrupt your function's execution and decide what you want to do.